# What is net::ERR_SSL_SERVER_CERT_BAD_FORMAT in my Ionic App?

Tags: json, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, woocommerce

I try to make an application using Ionic and Cordova with the help of WooCommerce but unfortunately some errors occurred in my browser(Google Chrome). My main goal here is to list all the products using JSON in the Console of Google Chrome like this:

[image]

This is the code I used in VS Code:
(testapi.page.ts)

```
    
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

    @Component({
    selector: 'app-testapi',
    templateUrl: './testapi.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['./testapi.page.scss'],
    })
    export class TestapiPage implements OnInit {

    url = "https://localhost/wordpress/";
    consumerKey = "ck_243b33c37ce0ad5787f97ae12ab386575d5e2926";
    consumerSecret = "cs_4417afb021542eabdeed00ea57de01259b2edeaa";
  

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.httpClient.get(this.url + 'wp-json/wc/v3/products?consumerKey=' + this.consumerKey + 
    '&consumerSecret=' + this.consumerSecret)
    .subscribe((data)=>{
      console.log(data);
    },
    (err)=>{

    }
    );

    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    }
```

This the output of Chrome with this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AClYS.png)

Comment: It means exactly what it says: Your at `localhost` installed certificate is in wrong or bad format. How did you generate it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTPS Client certificate error ERR\_SSL\_SERVER\_CERT\_BAD\_FORMAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32258589/https-client-certificate-error-err-ssl-server-cert-bad-format)

Comment: May I know how to generate localhost correctly? For now Im using XAMPP.

Comment: It is explained in the question I linked.